# Enum Associated Value Lookup

Tags: swift, enums

I have an enum with different associated value custom classes. Then trying to create a calculated value to determine if one particular type and return the value if so. The below works using a switch in the calculated value but seems a bit clumsy. Are there any cleaner approaches? Thanks.

```
private enum Situation: Equatable {
    case inLocation(LocationMO)
    case heldByBeing(BeingMO)
    case inContainer(PhysicalObjectMO)
}

private var isInSituation: Situation

var isInLocation: LocationMO? {
    switch isInSituation {
    case .inLocation(let validLocation): return validLocation
    default: return nil
    }
}
```

Comment: I wonder if this really is cleaner... it's at least shorter: `if case let Situation.inLocation(loc) = isInSituation { return loc } else { return nil }`

Comment: Yep, think that is cleaner than the switch with one real match. Thanks. Not sure why but I seem to love guard, so used this in the end: guard case Situation.inLocation(let validLocation) = isInSituation else {return nil}
        return validLocation